# Integration of BeanStream with Asp.Net website

Tags: asp.net, payment-gateway, beanstream

I need to implement BeanStream payment gateway in my C# code.I am new in payment gateway implementation. Can anybody help me with any demo project?
prior thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pages [here](https://beanstreamsupport.pbworks.com/w/page/26445764/Transaction%20Processing%20API) contains details information about integration API and there is a blog post which has a sample code in c#: [Sample C# code for BeanStream credit card processing](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2007/10/26/Sample-C-code-for-BeanStream-credit-card-processing.aspx)

Comment: Hello Waqas, thanks for the reply. but i have already seen this blog. The author of the blog is also searching for the SDK of BeanStream . The code file provided by the author is created by his own and he is not sure wether this code would work on Live or not. I asked BeanStream support team also but no answer from them even. Please if you find some other thing , share with me. thanks

Comment: according to BeanStreams's website, complete API/User Manual is available in Member's Section and can only be accessed by members. So if you have an account with them, you can look into the document.

Comment: thanks for your help. now i have a test account with BeanStream and i can access and start transactions on BeanStream at their sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Now i am well aware about BeanStream to give answers .
BeanStream accepets two types of Transaction modes:

The Standard Transaction Process 
With the Beanstream gateway, the basic transaction process occurs over three stages: 
• The transaction is submitted to the API 
• Automated error checks validate the information submitted in the request string 
• The data is submitted to the bank and a response is returned to the merchant’s server

we can use :

1. Basic HTTP Post
2. Server to Server Protocol
3. SOAP Method

Sample authorized Request string :

> https://www.beanstream.com/scripts/process_transaction.asp?merchant_id=123456789&requestType=BACKEND&trnType=P&trnOrderNumber=1234TEST&trnAmount=5.00&trnCardOwner=Joe+Test&trnCardNumber=4030000010001234&trnExpMonth=10&trnExpYear=10&ordName=Joe+Test&ordAddress1=123+Test+Street&ordCity=Victoria&ordProvince=BC&ordCountry=CA&ordPostalCode=V8T2E7&ordPhoneNumber=5555555555&ordEmailAddress=joe%40testemail.com

- Here you need to get an authorized Merchant_id and admin account (It could be on their Testing sandbox or your real admin account Merchant_Id.Replace the Merchent_Id with in this Request string before executing this Request)

Sample Authorized Response string:

> trnApproved=1&trnId=10001364&messageId=1&messageText=Approved&trnOrderNumber=1234TEST&authCode=TEST&errorType=N&errorFields=&responseType=T&trnAmount=5%2E00&trnDate=7%2F31%2F2009+11%3A57%3A12+AM&avsProcessed=0&avsId=0&avsResult=0&avsAddrMatch=0&avsPostalMatch=0&avsMessage=Address+Verification+not+performed+for+this+transaction%2E&cardType=VI&trnType=P&paymentMethod=CC&ref1=&ref2=&ref3=&ref4=&ref5=

hope this will be helpful to those who are willing to integrate with BeanStream.